# My state is not updating on first click when I try to post contact number for getting response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I am posting a mobile number using redux toolkit for getting OTP, api is working fine. Now I am redirecting my page according to response that I get. But its redirecting on next page on second click.

```
    const MobileNumperEnter = () => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const phoneNumberHere = useSelector((state) => state.phoneNumber);
    
    
        const onPressSendCode = () => {
        
                dispatch(createPost(inputContactState.toString()));
        
                console.log("phoneNumberHere", phoneNumberHere);
                console.log("successValue", phoneNumberHere.posts.success);

                // its not entering in if condition
        
                if (phoneNumberHere.posts?.status == 1) {
                    handleNavigate("OTPEnter", false, { deviceTypeParam: deviceType, contactNumberParam: inputContactState, deviceIdentifierParam: deviceIdentifier, deviceTokenParam: deviceToken });
                    
                    console.log("add", 2 + 2);
                    setAlertValue(false);
                }
                else {
                    setAlertValue(true);
                }
            }
    }
    
    return(
    <></>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use async await.

```
  const onPressSendCode =  async () => {
        
                dispatch(createPost(inputContactState.toString()));
        
                console.log("phoneNumberHere", phoneNumberHere);
                console.log("successValue", phoneNumberHere.posts.success);

                // its not entering in if condition
        
                if (phoneNumberHere.posts?.status == 1) {
                    handleNavigate("OTPEnter", false, { deviceTypeParam: deviceType, contactNumberParam: inputContactState, deviceIdentifierParam: deviceIdentifier, deviceTokenParam: deviceToken });
                    
                    console.log("add", 2 + 2);
                  await  setAlertValue(false);
    console.log('%c  alertValue: ', 'font-size:20px;background-color: #4b4b4b;color:#fff;', alertValue);
                
}
                else {
                    await setAlertValue(true);
    console.log('%c  alertValue: ', 'font-size:20px;background-color: #4b4b4b;color:#fff;', alertValue);

                }
            }
```

Comment: its not working. api respond after 1 to 2 seconds and thats why it directly goes to the else. I get respond of success 1 after 1 to 2 seconds and it doest not go in if condition and doesn't redirect me on next screen.